# 'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp' when working with lists

Tags: python, list

I've encountered the error `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp` when working with lists. More precisely, `p0 in points`, the `points.index(p0)` method call as well as the `points.remove(p0)` method call on the `points` list have been raising the error for a specific dictionary `p0` at a specific index of my `points` list. The `points`list contains 4700 dictionaries at the time of the error, reduced one dictionary by one from a list of 12000 objects until the error is raised. The `p0` dictionary contains a reference to another dictionary in the list, which in returns contains a reference to the `p0` object. The `p0` dictionary as well as the dictionary it contains a reference to appear twice in the `points` list before the error is raised by any of the three method call.

Where does this error come from?

**EDIT**: Here's the code that raises the error.

```
for roadType in roadTypes:
    points = roadPoints[roadType][:]

    while len(roadTails[roadType]) > 0:
        p0 = roadTails[roadType].pop()

        p1 = p0['next']
        points.remove(p0) # Where the error occurs
        points.remove(p1)

        while True:
            p2 = find(p1, points, 0.01)

            if p2:
                points.remove(p2)

                p3 = p2['next']
                points.remove(p3)

                if p3 in roadTails[roadType]:
                    roadTails[roadType].remove(p3)
                    break
                else:
                    p0, p1 = p2, p3
                    continue

            else: break
```

Here's the definition of `find`, where `dist` calculates the distance between two points.

```
def find(p1, points, tolerance = 0.01):
    for p2 in points:
        if dist(p2['coords'], p1['coords']) <= tolerance:
            return p2
    return False
```

Here's the full traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 314, in <module>
    points.remove(p0) # Where the error occurs
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: p0 is just a plain old python dict?

Comment: I still don't see any recursion. Show us more code! Where's `find` come from?

Comment: `p0` is a dictionary (created with `{}`).
I just added the definition of `find`.
As far as I understand the concept of recursion, there isn't any recursion in my code.

Comment: Can you add `sys.setrecursionlimit(20)` to the start of your code, and post the full traceback?

Comment: I added the full traceback with the recursion limit set to 20.

Comment: @Morhaus: Does it really not give you more than one level?

Comment: @Eric: The error seems to be raised by the native methods of the list object. The traceback doesn't show anything more than one level.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably you have a circular structure where one of your dicts refers to itself through a chain of `'next'`s, like this:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> b = {}
>>> a['next'] = b
>>> b['next'] = a
>>> a == b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

If you print out the dict, a circular reference would show up as `...`:

```
>>> a
{'next': {'next': {...}}}
```

Maybe this can help to find the problematic part of the dict.

Comment: Darn it, I was getting there! **+1**

Comment: This is indeed the case, but I don't understand why the native methods of a list would use `==` instead of `is` for methods such as `remove` and `index`? What type of object should I use to contain my data?

Comment: @Morhaus: That's just how the semantics of lists and dicts are. Probably you are better off to define your own `class` for your objects instead of using a `dict`. If you don't define any special comparison methods than `==` will be the same as `is` for those custom objects.