# Looping data: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django that iterate through items to see if they exists using get_or_create. Right now I'm having this problem

```
def insert_titles(self):
    game = None
    title = None
    for k,v in self.data.items():


        game_exists = Game.objects.all().get_or_create(game_name=v['title']) #will get RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
        print game_exists
```

Basically, this is an script that will run as a cron job, so I kind of have to iterate through a bunch of items to get to the point I want

```
            while True:
            try:

                data = strategy.process()
                filter = FilterGames(data, link)
```

Filter Games code:

```
def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.insert_titles()
    print "init"
```

I've done this in the past with Play Framework, maybe since I'm still inexperienced in Python I'm looking at it the wrong way, not sure how to proceed when it gives me this type of error. I have tried change the structure a bit to no avail. Weird thing is that if I use a `string` in `game_name` it will work as expected, but if I use data gathered from a loop, it starts throwing that error.

Finally, I want to know how to correct this type of error, and hopefully understand a bit more of why it does that.

Comment: Is the `insert_titles` function posted the entire function? Are you sure you aren't manipulating the `v` variable at all creating a circular reference like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246081/runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-in-cmp-when-working-with-lists

Comment: @DanHoerst Trace you requested http://pastebin.com/pC5q7FBJ and no I really haven't manipulated anything at all. If I remove that line with `get_or_create` everything works fine. So I'm assuming there's something wrong with that specific loop that makes django.db got "nuts"

Comment: does this only occur when executed from the cron job or will it happen from the shell? Like, if you boot up the django shell and do a `Game.objects.get_or_create(game_name='somename')`, what do you get?

Comment: @MikeFogel Everything was fine, I managed to fix it luckily. Posted up the answer of what went wrong hopefully others will notice this type of behavior and avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after poking and investigating why it did that. I noticed that the `type` of the object wasn't a true `string` type, or in this case `str`. I use BeautifulSoup to get data from some XML files and when I used `bs4.find().string` it gave me a `NavigableString` instead of a normal string.

So for future reference, be sure that the `type` is the right one. Feeding a `NavigableString` to Django filter gave me this unexpected error