# Official Django Tutorial Part1: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

Tags: python, django

as  per django tutorial,  I created the project and executed manage.py runserver as said in tutorial annd i got an error "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp"

Is there any way to correct this?

I got this as error:

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by >
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 370, in 
    class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 213, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(field.name, copy.deepcopy(field))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 265, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 257, in contribute_to_class
    cls._meta.add_field(self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 179, in add_field
    self.local_fields.insert(bisect(self.local_fields, field), field)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 56, in 
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other 
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other 
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other 
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other .........................
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

***Settings.py***

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1


USE_I18N = True


USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

SECRET_KEY = '+8nn@%#%d8r4##x*t==ja=kbm(514bng1m47yesv1wlsu#%)h4'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

***urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),
    enter code here
    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Can you paste your models file?

Comment: there is no model file. i was just following the tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/     Heading is The Development Server

Comment: @TarikSetia, what django version are you using? First thing coming into my mind is to reinstall django (may be you haven't removed the old django before installing new one..).

Comment: i got that error once and this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246081/runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-in-cmp-when-working-with-lists) helped me fix it.

Comment: post your urls.py and settings.py, please.

Comment: http://desk.stinkpot.org:8080/tricks/index.php/2007/04/fixing-python-error-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-in-cmp/

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev i m using django 1.5. Removing and reinstalling didn't work

Comment: @FernandoFreitasAlves I have posted the files

Comment: Delete the project, start over, and when you do `python manage.py runserver` you still get that error? At which step did this error come up? This is a rare error.

Comment: ALso, how did you install and remove django? `pip`?

Comment: @CppLearner executed python -c "import sys; sys.path = sys.path[1:]; import django; print(django.__path__)" to get path to django. then manual removal. Used PIP to reinstall

Comment: Can you try install django within a virtualenv?  We want to see if there are some side effect with the system wide python packages. And why do you have to manuall remove django? Pip has removal too. `pip uninstall django` i think.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259729/django-python-manage-py-runserver-gives-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-e

Comment: The problem is explained and resolved here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236556/django-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236556/django-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I just ran into this same error. Updating Python to v 2.7.5 worked for me.

I got the error when I switched accounts but tried to spin up the same Django project and I had only updated my Python version on the first account.