# manage.py runserver gives recursion error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying the Django tutorial;  when asked to run `manage.py runserver` I get the following 2 lines:

```
File "C:\python27\lib\functools.py",
 '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self), line 56, in <lambda>
```

for a dozen pages, followed by

```
Runtime error:  maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

I installed Django 1.5.1 with Python 2.7.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: We need code, or we can't really do anything.

Comment: A Google search gives many similar questions, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16259729/1258041)

Comment: you probably have some sort of loop that's executed all the time. A `manage.py runserver --traceback` might give you some more useful information

Comment: please submit the code that is causing the problem

Comment: I've tried some things to solve this, like run django 1.4 (it worked)

Comment: Finally, we got another solution that works with django 1.5. I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259729/django-python-manage-py-runserver-gives-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-e/17202476#17202476