# RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded after upgrading

Tags: python, django, django-wsgi

I've upgraded Django from 1.4.5 to 1.5.2 and now my website doesn't work. I get this error:

```
 RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I use virtualenv but for some reason in logs there is path to default python installation:

```
[Mon Sep 02 11:00:03 2013] [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
```

Maybe it's a problem with WSGI configuration. Here is the config for it:

```
<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:81 >
        AddDefaultCharset utf-8
        ServerName mywebsite.com
        CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/mywebsite.com.access.log combined
        DocumentRoot /var/www/empirik/data/www/mywebsite.com
        ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/mywebsite.com.error.log
        ServerAdmin my@mail.com
        ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
        SuexecUserGroup empirik empirik

        WSGIProcessGroup mywebsite.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/empirik/data/www/mywebsite.com/katalog/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess mywebsite.com \
                python-path=/home/envs/katalog/lib/python2.7/site-packages \
                python-home=/home/envs/katalog
        Alias /static/ /var/www/empirik/data/www/mywebsite.com/katalog/static/

        <Directory /var/www/empirik/data/www/mywebsite.com/katalog>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from All
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/empirik/data/www/mywebsite.com/katalog/static>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

UPDATE:
Here is full log: http://pastebin.com/wtfq6Rs3

Comment: That error clearly comes from python itself, you should show a full stacktrace, not just the last line, and show the offending code.

Comment: probably you made some modification in django default files, when you try to upgrade the new version cannot see the headers to update them .

Comment: @drabo2005, I definetely wouldn't make any changes in django itself.

Comment: I've added a link to full stacktrace to question.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259729/django-python-manage-py-runserver-gives-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what version of python you are running. I just had a similar problem running python 2.7.3 with Django. After updating to python 2.7.5 it ran successfully.