# Python Django manage.py exception

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm currently working my way through a course on Lynda for learning Django. I set up just a basic project using `django-admin startproject project_name`

After that, I tried running the `python manage.py` script to see a list of available commands. This is what I got back:

```
$ python manage.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 300, in <module>
    class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 274, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(field.name, new_field)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 694, in contribute_to_class
    cls._meta.add_field(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 277, in add_field
    self.local_fields.insert(bisect(self.local_fields, field), field)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
```

I haven't been able to find another question here on StackOverflow where someone has had this problem.

EDIT: In response to what Aditya said. When I run `python manage.py runserver` I get a similar output:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000003D19978>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 300, in <module>
    class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 274, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(field.name, new_field)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 694, in contribute_to_class
    cls._meta.add_field(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 277, in add_field
    self.local_fields.insert(bisect(self.local_fields, field), field)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
```

Comment: you may want to try `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Looks like a familiar  `functools` problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259729/django-python-manage-py-runserver-gives-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-e

Comment: @Aditya check edit

Comment: @MosesKoledoye the fix mentioned in that post worked. Thanks a ton!